# Get value from a SOAP response using XPath

Tags: soap, xpath

I have this SOAP response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <ConversionRateResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
     <ConversionRateResult>0.1492</ConversionRateResult>
  </ConversionRateResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

and I want to get the value:

0.1492

How do I state this using xpath?

My SoapUI response as 'raw' is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 31 Oct 2014 19:43:54 GMT
Content-Length: 316

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><ConversionRateResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET/"><ConversionRateResult>0.1482</ConversionRateResult></ConversionRateResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure XPath, trivially:

```
//ConversionRateResult/text()
```

But since XPath is usually embedded into a higher-level language like Java or XSLT, you might as well need (an XSLT example):

```
<xsl:template match="ConversionRateResult">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have updated my question. I am not sure I understand 'XSLT example'

Comment: Did you try `//ConversionRateResult/text()`? What happened?